# id3 exibir imagem do album em arquivo mp3 usando c# mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou construindo uma aplicação em C# e ASP.NET MVC e Razor que lê os dados de arquivos mp3, mas não consigo exibir a imagem do álbum. Já tentei várias bibliotecas disponíveis, extraio todas as informações menos a imagem do álbum (art cover album), creio que é necessário converter a informação bitmap para `jpeg` ou algum outro formato para ser exibido via `<img src>`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

[Esta biblioteca faz de modo prático o que você precisa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ID3/). [Será necessária esta extensão também](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ID3.Files).

A ideia é você converter [este `PictureManager`](http://id3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/PictureManager/) para Web. A ideia é carregar o arquivo usando um [`PictureFrame`](http://id3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Id3.Net/Frames/PictureFrame.cs). A ideia é usar [`FrameExtensions`](http://id3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Id3.Net.Files/FrameExtensions.cs) para isso:

```
using System.IO;

using Id3.Frames;

namespace Id3
{
    public static class FrameExtensions
    {
        public static void LoadImage(this PictureFrame frame, string filePath)
        {
            frame.PictureData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }

        public static void SaveImage(this PictureFrame frame, string filePath)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, frame.PictureData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado!

Comment: @Lucas A resposta atende sua pergunta? [Veja o tour para entender como o site funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!